# How should I indicate a package is not compatible with python 2?

Tags: python, python-packaging

I was researching a solution for [AVRO-2240](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2240) and thought that I should be able to use [environment markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers) as a better way to indicate that a package is designed for Python 3, but not for Python 2.

Environment markers are generally demonstrated with specific dependencies, as in

```
install_requires = ['argparse;python_version<"2.7"']
```

However, this refers to a dependency *argparse*, which doesn't always need to be installed. In this case I need to clarify that the package *itself* can't be installed in a python 2 environment. I tried

```
install_requires = ['python_version>="3"']
```

and ran `./setup.py develop` in python2 and python3 virtualenvs, respectively. That installed [python-version 0.0.2](https://pypi.org/project/python_version/) rather than giving any indication about environment compatibility.

I also added a trove classifier:

```
'Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only'
```

but that didn't make a difference -- I think those are only used for classifying packages on pypi itself.

Is there any way I can make python packaging tools aware that this code does not work with python<3 in a way that's useful to users and developers without making `setup.py` itself python 2 incompatible?